# Which easy task manager to use for small teams

Tags: project-management, calendar, task-management

I'd like to plan work for 3-5 person.... I would like to keep it as simple as possible, having one box per day with columns for different people (see photo). Each task can be assigned to one person or a sub-group. I'd do it in Excel, but having multiple rows per day is too anoying. Any suggestion for mac?
Thanks[image: ![nager]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE6k6.png)

Comment: We use [Trello](https://trello.com/), highly suggested!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a free task management tool like [Teamhood](https://teamhood.com/use-cases/task-management/). It allows you to plan tasks using list, Kanban, or Gantt. So, you could plan out the days in Gantt for example, and then monitor progress in Kanban.

It is free for up to 5 users, so you could also add your team members and collaborate on tasks more conveniently.

Answer (score 0):

For my own personal planning & task assignment, I am using the excellent (and free) [YouTrack](https://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/) by JetBraions (who make the best IDEs - worth knowing, if you are a coder).

I have set it up as a Kanban system, with swim lanes.

[image]

Check our the [features](https://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/features/) and let us know what you think.